# Where is the configuration file of Bitcoin-Qt kept?

Tags: bitcoin.conf

I keep getting this error:

```
EXCEPTION: N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15
program_options26invalid_config_file_syntaxEEEEE
the options configuration file contains an invalid line 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Where can I find the `bitcoin.conf` file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default location of bitcoin.conf depends on your operating system:

| OS | Path |
| --- | --- |
| Windows XP | C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf |
| Windows Vista, 7, 10 | C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin |
| Linux | /home/<username>/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf |
| Mac OSX | /Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf |

<sub>[Source](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File)</sub>

Not directly related to this question, but if you cannot find the configuration file at the above path: note that the configuration file is not necessary to run Bitcoin-Qt. *If it is not yet present, you can simply create it with any text editor*.

Comment: OSX -> OS X (e.g. ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X)

Comment: On my mac the bitcoin.conf file doesn't exist.  I'm not sure if simply creating it will cause it to be used by bitcoin-qt

Comment: @portforwardpodcast: Bitcoin Core will check for the existence of the file on startup, so yes, simply creating it is sufficient.

Comment: I use Linux Ubuntu(16.04 LTS) and i've found file /root/.config/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf but it's content was not like a normal bitcoin.conf

Comment: @PeterMortensen macOS, not OS X.

Comment: I have windows 8.1 and I can't find any bitcoin.conf file in my user folder...

Comment: For Bitcoin Core, if the file doesn't exist go to Settings (or Preferences in the top menu on macOS) and click the button labeled "Open Configuration File". This will create a bitcoin.conf file and open it in a text editor. Make your changes and save, then restart Bitcoin Core.

Answer (score 5):

Note that for Windows the location of the configuration folder where bitcoin.conf is located is saved in the registry.

Its default path is indeed `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin` but if that location was changed then in order to find the current folder you will have to look in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Bitcoin\Bitcoin-Qt` at the REG_SZ `strDataDir`.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that that refers to your bitcoin.conf.  There's platform-specific information on where to find it at: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File

Answer (score 1):

In bitcoin-core version 0.14.2, it looks for it in the data-dir folder
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File

The bitcoin.conf file is not created by default, you will need to create it yourself.
And also, I never had a `c:\users\[username]\appdata\roaming\bitcoin` folder as many online answers will suggest, this is because when I installed the bitcoin core program, I chose to put my data directory in a different place than default.