# Bitcoin-qt console on cmd

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, command-line-options

Is there a way to interact with Bitcoin-qt from Windows cmd and run commands like if I'm running them from Bitcoin-qt console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have `bitcoind` or `bitcoin-qt` running with the `-server` option, you can then use `bitcoin-cli` to run commands.

It's part of the bitcoind package.

If you have your conf file in a custom directory you'll have to specify that to bitcoin-cli as well, otherwise it should just work.

Comment: You'll also need to run bitcoin-qt with the -daemon option, or run bitcoind.

Comment: thx, answer updated to make that clear.

Comment: Oops, the answer below corrects me: you need -server, not -daemon (which is for running in the background).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you are trying to do is add one line to your [bitcoin.conf](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/debian/examples/bitcoin.conf) file.

> server=1

The file exists in one of these locations: "[Where is the configuration file of bitcoin qt kept](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11190/where-is-the-configuration-file-of-bitcoin-qt-kept)"

You are also required configure a username and password when you do this by adding these additional lines. Always use a new secure random password that is unique to only this service (don't re-use it anywhere, and don't commit it to a source code repository)

> rpcuser=Ulysseys
>   rpcpassword=YourSuperGreatPasswordNumber_DO_NOT_USE_THIS_OR_YOU_WILL_GET_ROBBED_385593

You can now run the bitcoin-cli.exe command from cmd.exe (it is installed in c:\program files\bitcoin\daemon)

It is also worth noting that you do not have to run bitcoin-qt you can choose to run bitcoind and interact with bitcoin-cli as well.